# How to set button to move with end of table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with a table, and next to the table, I have a button with an assigned macro. Currently, the button is at the beginning of the table. I would like the button to move along with the table's height, so that when I add new data, the button will automatically move to the end of the table (on the right)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you on the right track, it takes the body range of the table to get a position for the button on any change that occurs within the table. Expanding the tables range triggers it as well.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim topleft As Range
    On Error GoTo cleanexit
    With Me
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            lastrow = ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Row
            lastcol = ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.End(xlToRight).Column + 1
            Set topleft = .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)
            .Shapes("Button 1").Top = topleft.Top
            .Shapes("Button 1").Left = topleft.Left
        End If
    End With
cleanexit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```